# Using outlier records as a feature in model building

Tags: predictive-models, outliers, feature-engineering

I am exploring the Big Mart Sales III dataset and trying to understand if using outlier rows to build a feature for predictive modeling is a sound and correct approach.

This is how I have proceeded so far. I used the outliers of the dependent variable of the dataset, Outlet_Item_Sales, to introduce a new column, Sales_OL, to return TRUE or FALSE depending on whether that row has the sales as an outlier or not. I then summarised the data by the outlet, as in the table below.

As you can see, outlet OUT027 appears to have a significantly higher number of items where the sales values are identified as outliers. I am not sure if there is leakage or some other obvious reason this is not really useful, but this does seem to suggest that this outlet's sales figures for those items are potential predictive. How?, I am not so sure, and I wonder if someone could advise if this is a useful exploration to follow or is there a core issue in the approach that would make it inappropriate to use this to engineer a feature?

---

```
    Outlet_Identifier   tot `FALSE` `TRUE`
               <chr> <int>   <int>  <int>
 1            OUT027   935     832    103
 2            OUT017   926     907     19
 3            OUT035   930     914     16
 4            OUT013   932     917     15
 5            OUT049   930     919     11
 6            OUT046   930     920     10
 7            OUT045   929     920      9
 8            OUT018   928     925      3
 9            OUT010   555     555     NA
10            OUT019   528     528     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as a valid approach, but there is an important caveat -- you need to take precaution to avoid data snooping (that is, leakage, or "using data twice").

Namely, when marking a sales value as an outlier you must do it separately for training and testing datasets. If not, the predictive performance of your method will be inflated since the outliers were determined on the whole data set (training outliers are based also on values from the test set).

More precisely, I'd do the following:

(1) divide the data in training and test sets.
(2) on the training set use the distribution of sales values to mark each value as an outlier (for example check Tukey's method).
(3) do the same as in (2) on the test set (using only test data to form a distribution and decide outliers on test set)

Then, you can repeat (1)-(3) a number of times to evaluate average performance on the test sets.